# Testing a Next.js component with useFormState from 'react-dom' or alternatives

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jestjs

I'm currently working on a Next.js project and have a React component that utilizes [`useFormState`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hooks/useFormState). While attempting to write unit tests for this component using Jest, I encountered the following error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactdom.useFormState) is not a function or its return value is not iterable.
```

Below is a simplified version of the component:

```js
// Inside a Next.js project
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useFormState } from 'react-dom'

export default function MyFormComponent() {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(/* ... */);
  // ... rest of the component
}
```

The test currently looks like this:

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import MyCustomComponent from '../page'

describe('MyCustomComponent', () => {
    it('renders a heading', () => {
        render(<MyCustomComponent/>);

        screen.debug();
    })
})
```

Despite trying various approaches to mock or resolve this issue in my Jest tests, I haven't been successful. How to effectively test a Next.js component that uses `useFormState`?

Additionally, if React DOM isn't suitable for testing in a Next.js context, are there any recommended alternatives or best practices for managing form state in a Next.js React component that can be easily tested?

Comment: What _"various approaches"_?